# Fbx exported from Blender is Low Res in Unreal Engine

Tags: blender, unreal-engine4, fbx

I have a photogrammetry model that I edited in Blender, exported as fbx and imported to Unreal Engine. I also am exporting a png texture image from Blender and importing to Unreal Engine.

Once in Unreal Engine, the model looks decent from a distance, but when I zoom in more closely, the resolution is very low. I assume I'm making a mistake somewhere in the Bender export / Unreal Engine Import process.

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Thanks!

[image]
enter image description here